# JWT headless wordpress with javascript (custom plugin)

Tags: wordpress, rest, cookies, jwt, headless

**how to implement securly jwt with (vanilla or jquery) javascript and headless wordpress (php) **not by using any plugin****

i have 2 servers*
server 1 (vanilla js + html) app.example.com
server 2 (wordpress php)     example.com

in front end i make this ajax call (js)

```
        let email = 'test@test.com';
        let password = '123test';
     $.ajax({
        url: `https://example.com/wp-json/custom-route/v2/tologin/?email=${email}&password=${password}`,
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('error')
        }
    });
}
```

in back end the rest endpoint of this request (cutom plugin for wordpress php)

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom-route/v2', '/tologin/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'generate_jwt',
    ));
});
function generate_jwt(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    // get the username and password from the request
    $username = $request->get_param('username');
    $password = $request->get_param('password');
    // Authenticate the user
    $user = wp_authenticate($username, $password);
    // Check if the user is valid
    if (!is_wp_error($user)) {
        // Generate the JWT
        $issued_at = time();
        $expiration_time = $issued_at + 1800; // 30 minutes expiration
        $token_data = array(
            'iat' => $issued_at,
            'exp' => $expiration_time,
            'data' => array(
                'username' => $username,
                'user_id' => $user->ID,
            ),
        );
        $token = jwt_encode($token_data);
        setcookie('token-name-of-cookie', $token, [
            'expires' => $expiration_time,
            'path' => '/', 
            'domain' => '.example.com',
            'secure' => true,
            'httponly' => true,
            'samesite' => 'Strict',
        ]);
        return rest_ensure_response(array('token' => $token));
    } else {
        return rest_ensure_response(array('error' => 'Invalid credentials'), 401);
    }
}

function jwt_encode($data) {
    $secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $header = json_encode(['alg' => 'HS256', 'typ' => 'JWT']);
    $payload = json_encode($data);
    $base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));
    $base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . '.' . $base64UrlPayload, $secret_key, true);
    $base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));
    return $base64UrlHeader . '.' . $base64UrlPayload . '.' . $base64UrlSignature;
}
```

---

**SO FAR ITS OK i create the JWT**

Now for the cookie part

on inpector > application > cookies i can't see it,

but on inspector > network > cookies i see it. [token-name-of-cookie with the jwt...]

---

after that i want **make a new one request** to a new rest end point to resive some data of the logedin user
so on a button click
i make this request from (js)

```
function member_data() {  
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/custom-route/v2/getdata',
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        success: function(userdata) {
           console.log(userdata)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('error')
        }
    });
}
```

---

end the rest endpoint of this request (cutom plugin for wordpress php)

---

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {exit;}
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom-route/v2', '/getdata', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_member_data',
    ));
});
function get_member_data($request) {
    $token = isset($_COOKIE['token-name-of-cookie']) ? $_COOKIE['token-name-of-cookie'] : null;
    
    error_log("----- token --");
    error_log($token);
    error_log("----- token --");

    $decoded_token = jwt_decode($token);
    if ($decoded_token) {
        $user_id = $decoded_token->data->user_id;
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        );
        return rest_ensure_response($user_data);
    } else {
        return rest_ensure_response(array('error' => 'Invalid token'), 401);
    }
}
function jwt_decode($token) {
    $secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
    list($header, $payload, $signature) = explode('.', $token);
    $decoded_header = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $header)), true);
    $decoded_payload = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $payload)), true);
    $computed_signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $header . '.' . $payload, $secret_key, true);
    $computed_signature_base64 = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($computed_signature));
    if ($signature === $computed_signature_base64) {
        return $decoded_payload;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

end there is the problem **the $token is empty**

---

so i read "for security use **httponly**"
"**The browser automatically includes the HttpOnly cookie** in the headers of subsequent requests to the same domain."

In **front end i can't create a httponly cookie** (js has not access to httponly cookies)
In **back end i create it but i can't use it for new requests**?

*I could save it to a non httponly cookie in js or in local/session storage
and send it i know.. but *the right way is to be secure for xxs ....*

**So can anybody help me and the rest of us that we have not implemented this yet?
Thank you**

Comment: sry not xxs  --> *xss